# How to insert id using typeorm mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typeorm

I am trying to insert the id of a record using typeorm mongodb.
I have created an Entity class for User, then I created a service for saving user into the database.

```
@Entity()
export class User {
    @ObjectIdColumn()
    @Transform(({ value }) => value.toHexString())
    id: ObjectID;

    @Column()
    firstname: string;

    @Column()
    lastname: string;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    email: string;

    @Column()
    @CreateDateColumn()
    createdAt: Date;

    @Column()
    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updatedAt: Date;

    constructor(user?: Partial<User>) {
        Object.assign(this, user);
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class UsersService implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly usersRepository: Repository<User>
  ) { }

  async onModuleInit() {
    console.log(await this.usersRepository.save(new User({
      "id": "123456789012",
      "lastname": "Admin",
      "email": "admin@mail.com",
      "password": "password"
    })));
  }
}
```

But, the log shows different id